# How to reset looping of Start function using button in Unity 3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Possible to reset looping of void Start using button in unity ?

```
void Start()
{

        if (NoAnsweredQuestion == null || NoAnsweredQuestion.Count == 0)
        {
            NoAnsweredQuestion = question.ToList<Question>();
        }
        StartCoroutine("CountDownTimer");
        SetcurrentQuestion();

}
```

Comment: cant understand your question

Comment: Why don't you create a public function that does exactly the same and call it on your UI button?

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to execute the code the in the Start Method multiple times, you have a bad design, but if you really need to have it in the start Method just destroy the script with a diffrent one and put it on again.

What I would recommend is, that you move this code just in the method that gets executed if the button gets pressed.

Anyway like 'Lestat' said your question is really strange and I can not really understand it aswell.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function using:

```
public void YourFunctionName (){
    if (NoAnsweredQuestion == null || NoAnsweredQuestion.Count == 0)
        NoAnsweredQuestion = question.ToList<Question>();

    StartCoroutine("CountDownTimer");
    SetcurrentQuestion();
}
```

If you are using Canvas (which I recommend you do!), you simply add a new button:

[image]

And then add the function to the button using the '+' sign, drag your GameObject (with your script attached to it) and select the class and then the function (must be public in order to work).

[image]

And I guess this will solve your problem.